# «...открытие программы «День России» с участием актёров театра и кино – Василием Лановым...»?

Tags: согласование, падежи, склонение-фамилий

«...открытие программы «День России»  с участием актёров театра и кино – Василием Лановым...»?

Верно ли падежное окончание у В. Ланового?

Answer (score 2):

**С участием .... Василия Ланового.**

Похожее предложение из Нацкорпуса:

> Деньги, предназначенные для транспортировки трупа, они, естественно, пропивают, что приводит к ряду анекдотических ситуаций **с участием актеров Сергея Маковецкого и Константина Хабенского**. [Мария Кувшинова. Киберпанк по-русски (2002) // «Известия», 2002.01.24]

Не уверен по поводу тире. Предложение приведено не полностью, поэтому можно только предположить, что оно такого типа:

*Завтра состоится мероприятие с участием актёров театра и кино Иванова, Петрова и Федорова.*

Если ударение падает на конкретные фамилии, то тире не нужно. Если же хотите сделать акцент на том, что участвуют актёры театра и кино, то фамилии можно рассматривать как уточнение и тогда тире уместно, но все равно требуется родительный падеж: Василия Ланового, Ивана Иванова, Петра Петрова и т. п.

Comment: М_Г,, тире на месте, если оно отделяет однородные члены, пусть и фамилии, автор вправе его поставить.

Answer (score 1):

**Выбора падежа**

Члены однородного ряда имеют тот же падеж, что и обобщающее слово (приложение).

1) ...открытие программы «День России» с участием **актёров** (Р.п.) театра и кино – **Василия Ланового** (Р.п.)...»?

2) ...открытие программы «День России» **с актерами** (Т.п.) театра и кино – **Василием Лановым** (Т.п.)...»?

Примечание

**Тире, как верно было указано в ответе М_Г, ставится,** если ударение падает и на приложение в роли обобщающего слово, и на фамилии (обычно называется  несколько фамилий). В этом случае перед однородным рядом делается пауза, предупреждающая о последующем перечислении.

Если это приложение, например, перед двумя фамилиями, то пауза не делается и **тире не ставится.**

Answer (score 0):

У Вас всё верно, вкупе с тире.

**[Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482)**

13.1.2. Фамилии с формальным показателем *-ск-* склоняются в мужском и женском роде и во множественном числе как прилагательные. <...>

Русские фамилии, склоняющиеся как прилагательные и не имеющие показателя *-ск-,* относительно немногочисленны; к ним относятся: ***Благой, Толстой, Боровой, Береговой, Лановой, Броневой, Дикий, Гладкий, Поперечный*** и т. п. (см. перечень таких фамилий в книге: А. В. Суперанская, А. В. Суслова. Современные русские фамилии. М., 1981. С. 120—122).

*...с участием актёров театра и кино – Василием Лановым...*